# Search a missing closing tag in XML file

Tags: xml

I have a XML file of size 1.2 GB.

```
cat tpl.xml | grep -i "</es:vsDataE1Ttp>" | wc -l
   30844

cat tpl.xml | grep -i "<es:vsDataE1Ttp>" | wc -l
   30845
```

From above we can see that on Closing tag is missing. I want to know at what place in the XML file this tag is missing, means its not closing. Even if i can get the line number i can work out my original problem.

Please help me in this.

Comment: I am confused, you are counting double quotes which are all about attributes and not about tags?!

Comment: No no... I pasted the contents inside that quotes but don't know why it appeared in the post. I am pasting again:

> cat tpl.xml | grep -i "</es:vsDataE1Ttp>" | wc -l
   30844

> cat tpl.xml | grep -i "<es:vsDataE1Ttp>" | wc -l
   30845

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `xmllint --valid --stream myfile.xml`?

Edit: Added `--stream` as you are dealing with very large files.

Comment: This is an automatically generated XML file from some tool. So we dont modify or generate it manually. That is the reason i just wanted to know the place where the tag is missing.

Comment: xmllint should tell you where the tag is missing - afterwards you can report a bug to the generating tool which produces the invalid XML file.

Comment: > xmllint --valid --stream tpl.xml.bck
tpl.xml.bck:4: parser warning : xmlns: URI configData.xsd is not absolute
    xmlns:gn="geranNrm.xsd" xmlns="configData.xsd">
                                                  ^
tpl.xml.bck:4: validity error : Validation failed: no DTD found !
    xmlns:gn="geranNrm.xsd" xmlns="configData.xsd">
                                                  ^
Document tpl.xml.bck does not validate
tpl.xml.bck : failed to parse

Comment: If you don't have an XSD or DTD to validate the file, you can use: `xmllint -noout myfile.xml` to determine if it is well-formed.

Comment: You rock D.R.   The last command you gave it worked... !!! Thanks a lot... You made the day... Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Use a library such as `SimpleXML` and e.g. scripting language and try to parse the file. With a little luck (given the filesize), the library will error out on the missing tag and give you an error message indicating where the problem is.

For example, in PHP:

```
try {
   simplexml_load_file ($your_file);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```